# Htaccess rewrite clean categories & articles

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like this:
example.com/index.php?p=blog&category=blog&article=blog-test

But I'd like to have it look like:
example.com/blog/blog/blog-test

How would I be able to do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+)$ index.php?p=$1&category=$2&article=$3 [L]
```

Comment: I apologize... Blog isn't the page. Everything will be served through the index. Please see update question.